# jquery live click with onclick server side

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, gridview, jquery

I am developing ASP.Net Web Application using jquery and I'm new in a jquery , I've a grid view "grdVwFirst" with expand button,after clicking on expand a dialogue with another grid view "grdVwDetails" is displayed , this expand button has a live click as following

```
 $("#MainContent_grdVwFirst input[id*='btnDetails'] ").live('click', function (e) {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        $("#MainContent_grdVwDetails").GridviewFix().dataTable({
            "bFilter": false, "bJQueryUI": true
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

and the expand button exists in a templateitem as following

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDetails" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Styles/images/plus-5-16.png" />
 </ItemTemplate>
```

This All are working fine , 
**the problem** is that I don't know where to bind my data to the new grid view "grdVwDetails" in the server side as onClick function doesn't work with the live click , as i can't use onclick because it's used in jquery live click

Comment: is there any answer ?! or my question isn't clear enough

Comment: Are you working on Nested Gridview functionality and want to bind inner gridview clientside?

Comment: @Nil nope , I've a main grid view which have column with expand button , this button shows a new dialogue box (show and hide divs ) with another grid view, my question is where can i bind the new grid view server side as onclick is reserved in jquery call

Answer (score 0):

Query.live is deprecated from version 1.7 and removed from version 1.9

You must to use .on

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: how this can solve my problem, everything is working fine with live and livequery but i need to know where can i bind my data to the new grid view ?

Comment: #MainContent_grdVwFirst input[id*='btnDetails'] change to #btnDetails
I am not sure but input[id*='btnDetails'] is not correct syntax

Comment: mmm ,,after data binding every button id is concatenated to th id of the row so i use this select query with contains command , and again it's working as expected and no errors the problem is finding where can i bind my data to the new grid view

Answer (score 0):

As documented in the [jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) documentation this utility was deprecated in version 1.7 and removed in 1.9 in favor of j[jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

If you are using a third party library which uses [jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or unable to change to use [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), then there is a [migration plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme) released by jQuery.

The migration plugin contains all the code required for backward compatibility. Include [migration plugin js file](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js) into your project and jQuery.live should work fine.

Comment: ok, i'll try it , but does this helps me using also onclick event in expanding button for binding data to the new grid view in server side, as i want 2 onclick event server side to bind the data as well as jquery on(click,function(){ , to convert gridview to jquery datatable